# Ionic 3 Google Map flickers during view transition

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm using Ionic 3, and working on iPhones (all versions), and when my view transitions to a view with a Google Map in it, for a second the map flickers and I can still see in the background the previous view. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to destroy map while performing transition to another page using map.destroy() method. Hope it helps.